# Ошибка TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable при парсинге сайта

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, csv, bs4

Пытаюсь сделать свой парсер python для сайта Animego, но у меня появляется ошибка:

*TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable*

Код парсера:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

def save():
    with open('example2.csv', 'w') as myfile:
        writer = csv.writer(myfile)
        writer.writerows(all)
    print("Writing complete")

def parse():
    url = "https://animego.org/"
    r = requests.get(url=url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
    divs = soup.findAll("div", {"class":"animes-list-item media"})
    all = []
    for div in divs:
        link = div.find("a",{"class":"d-block"}).get('href')
        title = div.find("div",{"class":"h5 font-weight-normal mb-1"}).text
        ser = div.find("span",{"class":"anime-year mb-2"}).find('a',{"class":"text-link-gray text-underline"}).text
        img = div.find("div",{"class":"anime-list-lazy lazy"}).get('data-original')
        sd = div.find("div",{"class":"description d-none d-sm-block"}).text
        all.append(div)

    save()

parse()
```

Comment: Вот какая ошибка
Writing complete
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>
    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
    exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 26, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 25, in parse
  File "<string>", line 8, in save
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

[Program finished]

Comment: 1. Вы не передаете значение all при вызове save() и не принимаете его в качестве аргумента в def save(); 2. Вы к all апперлите объекты BeautifulSoup, а не значения link, title etc...

Answer (score 0):

- В функцию записи файла нужно, видимо, передать значение:

```py
def save(all):
    with open('example2.csv', 'w') as myfile:
        writer = csv.writer(myfile)
        writer.writerows(all)
```

- В список all добавлять не объекты BeautifulSoup, а распарсенные строки:

```
all.append((link, title, ser, img, sd))
```

- И все заработает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо.